# Correct way to sing

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Many Jewish songs have a low part and a high part. For example: Acheinu, Ko Amar Hashem Zacharti, Habbet, Baruch Hu Elokeinu...

For these songs, my Yesiva is careful to sing the low part twice, the high part twice, the low part twice, and then the high part twice.

However, other places sing them differently. Some recite each part only once at a time, or end off with an extra high part, or do the whole sequence one or three times.

What is the correct way of singing such songs?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Are you in medrash shmuel? That sounds like such a medrash thing to do

Comment: The way to sing the tune in situ is different from the way to sing it when it's used for e.g. "_Kel adon_". I seem to recall reading that in [_Aroch Hashulchan_](/a/55466).

Answer (score 5):

The low part must be sung twice in a row, as the pasuk says (Bereishis 38:9):

Vayeda Onan ki **lo lo** yihyeh hazara

However, there's another pasuk that seems to teach us the same thing (Devarim 32:5):

Shicheis **lo lo** banav mumam dor ikesh uf'saltol

So the low part must be sung twice in a row, two times, so your yeshiva is doing things correctly.

Comment: The poem Beis Kur by Ibn Ezra for Shabbos Channuka has the stanza "high, high...bei kur" this is a proof that the high part too must be song twice.

Comment: I was looking for a source for high, but it escaped me.